# Android - Is there a system broadcast intent when an app is killed to reclaim resources?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

I'm attempting to write a BroadcastReceiver to be notified when the Android OS kills an app in order to reclaim resources. I've tried filtering on "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" but I never seem to receive that broadcast, even when I force close an application.

So, am I using the correct intent action filter? If not, what is the proper one? Or is this simply not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve,

Unfortunately, if there is such an Action, it is not documented. The closest that you could get to is to run a service in the "foreground" and check if a particular application is running. There is no reason, after all, that you couldn't create such an Intent.

FuzzicalLogic